# Keep custom read more link on the same line as excerpt text

Tags: custom-post-types, excerpt

I am using `the_excerpt()` to display an excerpt for a custom post.

I then use this code to change the default "Continued" link to "Read more" which is working fine:

```
function bm_excerpt_more_link( $excerpt ){
   $post = get_post();
   $excerpt .= '<a href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '">Read more</a>';
   return $excerpt;
}
add_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'bm_excerpt_more_link', 21 );
```

However the "Read more" link is shown on the next line, outside the excerpt's `<p>` tag.

E.g.

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do 
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
<a href="http://mytheme.dev/news-post-five/">Read more</a>
```

Is it possible to keep the "Read more" text on the same line as the excerpt, within the `<p>` tag of the excerpt, in the same way as the default "Continued" link?

E.g.

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do 
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua … <a 
href="http://mytheme.dev/news-post-five/">Continued</a></p>
```

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple function that changes the output of the “[…..]” text and replace with the permalink.

```
function bm_excerpt_more_link( $more ) {
 $post = get_post();
return '<a href="'.get_the_permalink($post->ID).'">Read More...</a>';
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'bm_excerpt_more_link', 21 );
```

Or you can remove "p" tag by adding this below line before your post loop.

```
  remove_filter('the_excerpt', 'wpautop');
```